# Convert JSON String into ArrayList of ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, json, arraylist, collections

Is there any simple way to convert below JSON String into ArrayList of ArrayList using Java?

**Input**

```
{
    "results": [{
            "key_1_1": "val_1_1",
            "key_1_2": "val_1_2"
        },
        {
            "key_2_1": "val_2_1",
            "key_2_2": "val_2_2"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
[["val_1_1","val_1_2"],["val_2_1","val_2_2"]]
```

Comment: Try to do what you have asked about and post any attempts you do.  Then we can help you modify your attempt into something that will work :)

Answer (score -1):

Simply loop through it, and do following

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonArrayString);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
      list.add( jsonArray.getString(i) );
   }
```